# How to implement a for-loop for an SFTP-Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, server, sftp

1. I am setting up an SFTP-Server with Nodejs with several functions
   implemented. (Read, delete, download…)

   The problem is, that the server only sees the content of the first
   file in the directory he reads. Meaning while I can see all files
   lined up with the help of my WinSCP Client, it only opens the
   content of the first file. When I click on the second file, it shows
   the content of the first again, although the file is named different
   and so on. When I try to download the files, same happens; you can
   download each file, but as soon as you open them there is the
   content of the very first file in my directory. I know that it has
   to do with the for-Loop I wasn't able to implement for a while now. 
   I hope you guys can help with some experience/ expertise.

   I used dummy user names and Paths for this website.

   ```
   session.on("readdir", function(files, responder) {
   var i = 0;
             responder.on("dir", function() {
               **if (results[i])** {
                 console.warn(now + " Returning file: " + results[i]);
                 responder.file(results[i]);
                 **return i++;**
               } else {
               return responder.end();
               } 
             });
             return responder.on("end", function() {
               return console.warn(now + " Directory has been read");
             });
           });

   session.on('stat', function(path, statkind, statresponder) {
         statresponder.is_file();             
         statresponder.permissions = 0o777; 
         statresponder.uid = 1;             
         statresponder.gid = 1;                   
         statresponder.size = 1234;        
      });

   session.on("readfile", function(path, writestream) {
         var i = 0;
         **if(results[i])** {
           console.log(now + " Reading file: " **+ results[i]);**
           return fs.createReadStream("KKK_Files/"+results[i]).pipe(writestream); 
        }
         else { 
          console.warn(now + " no file to read");
         }
       }) 

   session.on("delete", function(path, writestream) {
   session.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
         if (err) throw err;
         var i = 0;
         fs.unlink("KKK_Files/" **+ results[i],** function(err){
            if ( err ) {
                console.log( "Error, problem starting SFTP: %s", err );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     console.log(now + " all Files have been deleted");
                    }
                });
             });

           session.on("download", function(path, fastGet) {
               var moveTo = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/file.DAT";
               if (err) throw err;
               var i = 0;
                    fs.fastGet("KKK_Files/" + 
                           **results[i],**moveTo,function         
                    (err) {if ( err ) {
                     console.log("Error downloading the file", err);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   console.log(now + "Successfully downloaded");
                   }
                 });
               });
                files.forEach(files => {
             results.push(files);
           });
         });
       });
    });






   for**(i=0; i<results.length; i++)** {
           console.log(now + " Reading file: " + results[i]);
           return fs.createReadStream("KKK_Files/" + results[i]).pipe(writestream); 
       }if (err) throw err;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using local variable i for index variable on your results. This local variable has value 0 each time the event occurs.

```
// problem with your variable name, change variable names and try to understand scope.
var i = 0;
```

You may want to use index variable outside of the the event listener. Try with one event at a time.